# JSON Data are undefined in JavaScript after server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have trouble with my script in PHP which get a json array.

I use the following code:

```
$(function() {

  $("img").click(function() {
    auswahl = $( this ).attr("id");

    $.get('mail_filebrowser_add2.php?datenID=' + auswahl, function(data) {
      alert("Server Returned: " + data.hello);
    });
    return false; 

});
```

I expect the the alert show "Server Returned: abc".
Because the value of the key "hello" from the JSON Object is "abc".

But I get only the information "Server Returned: undefined".

If I run the script where the JSON query comes from it looks fine:
`{"hello":"abc"}`

Any idea what i do wrong?

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `+ auswahl'`. Is it your real code or just an example?

Comment: You are adding an extra single quote after `auswah1`, also auswah1 has the value you expect?

Comment: `$.get( 'mail_filebrowser_add2.php?datenID=' + auswahl, function( data ) { // ... }, "json");`

Comment: @ishegg I think you can post it as answer.

Comment: @u_mulder I’m not sure. `$.get()` is supposed to be able to guess the `dataType` so it might well be something else.

Comment: We actually need to know if this is a copy/paste of the OP's actual code (which should throw an error and not run at all) or if it is a rewrite for our benefit (then the OP needs to post the _actual_ code instead) before we continuing debugging.

Comment: Assuming what y'all are saying are typos is it possible OP needs to parse the JSON string `data` to an object before accessing it using dot notation?

Comment: First of all, JSON data does not show the `undefined` message in PHP, but in JavaScript as your `data.hello` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks first. This is a copy from my script. The GET works fine. The script mail_filebrowser_add2 returns as JSON {"hello":"abc"}. But the data.hello output show undefinded. What I must do define hello that I get the abc as value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse to parse the data into JSON object,

```
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then use `parsedObject.hello`